# A semicolon or an em dash?

Tags: american-english, semicolons, em-dashes

"Hediger acquired a drone after losing half of her harvest in one year to weeds. She estimates that identifying problems faster with timely crop data and using less weed killer will save her tens of thousands of dollars in **future years.** Considerably more than the $7,000 she paid for the drone and any potential costs associated with reviewing images."

In order for the bolded section to be grammatically correct, do I need to use a semicolon (;) or an em dash (-)? I would also appreciate it if you could explain the reason why as well.

Comment: You might be interested in the Lexico [punctuation guide](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: A semicolon doesn't work because the string 'Considerably ... images.' does not constitute a main clause (a complete sentence). Not that it's not acceptable as it stands – sentence fragments used judiciously are seldom frowned upon in informal writing. Provided they're given capital letters (ie not after semicolons.) // A dash (we tend not to subcategorise in the UK) would also be fine in all registers. A colon would work identically, but they're considered old-fashioned. The dash (and the colon) are used to introduce further considerations (here the justification for the  $7,000 overhead).

Comment: That's an en dash, not an em dash.

Comment: This isn't a question of being grammatically correct, either. It's stylistic.

Comment: You never ***need*** to use an em-dash. In this instance, a comma will do perfectly well (although an em-dash also works).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Speak for yourself. Some if us in Britain still value traditional typography, having grown up with the stylesheets of publishers who cared for such things. I would always encourage people to aim high, not sink to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's neither an em dash (—) nor an en dash (–) in the question. In fact, it's just a regular hyphen (-).

Comment: It's also possible to enclose every after *future years* in parentheses and as part of the same sentence.

Comment: @David I was speaking of what I believe is the norm. [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/hyphen-en-dash-or-em-dash/) has: 'In British English, an en dash with spaces before and after ... is often used instead of an em dash.' [TheWriter](http://www.thewriter.com/what-we-think/style-guide/dashes/): 'Em dashes aren’t used so much in the UK these days.' Picking(!) a style guide, [the University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) has: 'Dashes and hyphens ...
m-dash ...
Do not use; use an n-dash instead'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Nothing to do with grammar. Just one house’s style guide.

Comment: @David You're changing the subject. 'Speak for yourself' implies that a subjective view has been given. I've given evidence that (a) others – reasonably respected organisations – agree that  'Em dashes aren’t used so much in the UK these days'  and (b) the style guide of a prestigious body recommends not using the m-dash. I haven't mentioned grammar, though a reference I gave had a name based on that word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — The author tagged the question as American English, so why are you advising him about British English? Indeed, why are you advising him at all? Comments are not for answering questions.

Comment: @David (1) 'American English' doesn't exist, and neither does 'British English'. Apparently the NYT online doesn't use the em-dash.  I'm advising that 'rules' are often (as here) preferences, however loudly those with particular preferences shout for their favourite styles. OP's 'In order for the bolded section to be grammatically correct, do I need to use ... or an em dash ... ?' shows that loud shouters have misled at least some. (2) When the question is a duplicate, some consider it a more friendly approach to reply in a 'comment' rather than not at all. Using an 'answer' endorses repeats.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I think we’ve been here before with the question of ignoring the injunction in the comment box — you will be familiar with my post on meta. I did an analysis of the use of dashes in answer to another question a while back, but I’m in the garden with my phone and the sun is shining and this is Glasgow and it may never happen again and the question has been closed. Another day.